# PDFBox program doesn't read non English characters properly from pdf

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdf-reader

iText program replaced with PDFBox Program to read  pdf file.

```
            public static void main(String[] args) {  

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                PDDocument     pd;  
                BufferedWriter wr;  

                try {  
                    File input = new File("C:\\test\\ExtractTextFromThis.pdf");    // The PDF file from where you would like to extract  
                    File output = new File("C:\\test\\OutPut.txt");    // The text file where you are going to store the extracted data
```

// Load document.

```
                    pd = PDDocument.load(input);  // load document
                    pd.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
```

// trying to check language

```
                        System.out.println(pd.getDocumentCatalog().getLanguage());
                        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper("UTF-8");  // Initializing PDFTextStripper Object with UTF-8 encoding.

       //          PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea("UTF-16");
                    // Please provide example for this. In attached document,I want to extract text from rectangle. There are 30 boxes.

                    wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output)));  
                    stripper.writeText(pd, wr);
                    System.out.println(stripper.getText(pd));  
                    String text = stripper.getText(pd);  
                    char[] cArr = text.toCharArray();  

// Here is the problem. It's not printing characters of Kannada language within its UTF Range. 
//printing chracters -- their integer value --  their Hexadecimal value  
                    for (int i = 1; i < 130; i++) {  
                        System.out.println(cArr[i] + "\t" + (int) cArr[i] + "\t" + Integer.toHexString(cArr[i]));  
                    }  

                    if (pd != null) {  
                        pd.close();  
                    }  

                    wr.close();  
                } catch (Exception e) {  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }  
            }
```

Comment: What have you done to try to get it working yourself? Have you tried running it through a debugger? If so - on which line(s) of code did you find the problem to be?

Comment: I tried to print character,  its integer value, its Hexadecimal value, to see why character is not of Kannada language. The for-loop does it. So I think there is the problem. Or problem could be in stripper.getText() itself because cArr[] just stores whatever getText() returns.

Comment: The above program gives following output.    ⁢⁂⁋߈ߐ޻ޚߐ߂ῡ⁔ޚߋῇ‚ߍ ῥ⁍ߌ޽ߛ⁭߄߂ެߍ ⁎
1
ߐ߄ߋ⁲
ޚ޽⁤߂
 ߍ ߐު‭ߛ⁩ޠ⁑ޚޤ
⁎‡ޤ޽⁍޽
TYA3250032
Ῡߐߋ߃߈ῖߐ޸⁲ެޚ⁌
ߐ߄ߋ⁲޽޶ޚެ
But need following output in Kannada characters range..1




TYA3250032
 

Comment: @Zafar the current state of your question indeed is hardly well-defined. But when starting anew, I would advise you to also supply a sample pdf from which the Canadian characters are extracted incorrectly. It is possible that the glyphs simply do not contain the information which Unicode character they correspond with.

Comment: sure. how can I attach the pdf file here please.. When I try to paste characters from pdf file they're not copying properly. So I have attached the pdf I am reading in gmail account. User: pdfreader2012@gmail.com and passowrd: 12345pdf  Please let me know if you have more suggestions.

Comment: Oh, I only saw just now that you posted your code and output as mail (putting them somewhere on a web server or including them in your question is way more common). Unfortunately you still did not include the PDF you use as base document.

Comment: sorry, it has now been included in email. Please check now. Please let me know where I could include on web-server. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see. I actually thought "Kannadian" was a special kind of writing "Canadian" and the special characters were some French accented characters. Now I see it is a completely different character set... Something Indic? Anyway, I'll have a look at the document in office on Monday.

Comment: yes, it is an Indian language. It called Kannada. It doesn't let me copy exactly as it appears. It has range in UTF-8 character set. once again thank you for looking into it!!

Comment: In UTF-8 encoding it is U+0C80 to U+0D7F. In the below URL, there is a drop-downlist. Please scroll to select Kannada. http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl

Comment: Ok, I've had a look at the PDFs now and, unfortunately, I've got bad news: The font for the Kannada characters in your PDF is a composite font (with a Type2 CIDFont) with an Identity-H encoding without a ToUnicode map. This means that character data in the PDF actually only is a sequence of pointers to individual glyphs without any correspondence glyph to Unicode code. This implies that the character data cannot be axtracted from your file with a general prpose solution like iText.

Comment: As far as general purpose solutions go, you most likely have to resort to rendering the PDF to an image and apply OCR to it.

Comment: If you do have very many of these documents, you might consider programming some in-depth embedded font analysis. Maybe somewhere in those structures a hint to the unicode of the individual glyph is burried. Otherwise you might OCR the individual glyphs (thus making OCR accuracy high) or compare the glyphs to known ones (the CIDFont subsets well-known Microsoft fonts) and so determine their associated unicode code.

Comment: yes I have many of these documents. do you have the sample embedded-font analysis code I can try please?

Comment: No, unfortunately I've not yet needed to resort to such a measure. It should be possible, though, as the specifications are openly available as are numerous applications implementing a certain degree of font analysis.

Comment: thanks. I will first go through specifications. Did you mean adobe font specifications or anything else? Please give me some steps ex: 1) Go through specifications xyz (all possible specifications) 2) Search for corresponding classes in itext-library 3) try again.

Comment: You should start with the chapter on fonts in the PDF specification (ISO 32000-1:2008) which as copy is available for download at http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf and continue with the referenced documentations as required. With that knowledge, the current iText parser package, and your documents start expanding the parser classes to also map the character identifiers in your PDF to unicode codes.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your help! I am sorry to thank you so late. I could not completely understand the pdf specifications. I am still working on to extract the text. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to consider a shortcoming of iText actually is a misconception in your algorithm to extract page content:

You assume that the strings in the contents stream actually are Unicode encoded. They need not be, and often especially non-ASCII characters are not. Translation information (if any is there at all!) is contained in the font dictionaries.

Additionally you assume that all text strings are contained directly in the contents stream. This need not be true: the content stream can refer to other objects which in turn can contain text which your code won't find.

And also you assume that the content entry of a page is a single indirect stream. It actually can be an array of them, too.

I would advise you to switch to using the text parsing classes of iText in the parser package which take all those things and more stuff into account.

Comment: Please disregard the above program. I had two programs one using itext and other using pdfbox. The output shown in my fist post above is a pdfbox program output. Itext looks little complex to me. My PDFBox program is as follows. Please give me your suggestions.

Comment: Hi Jon B, Kay, bmargulies, Sean Owen, bensiu, I couldn't understand why my post is ambigious? I explained problem, posted code, programs output, desired output. And now I posted revised code with where the problem is. Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: @Zafar I don't have experiences with PDFBox text recognition and, therefore, cannot help there. I don't consider iText text recognition complicated either, by the way, if done using the classes from the parser package.

Comment: sure. I will try with classes from parser package.

Comment: As commented above, please also supply a sample pdf. Maybe the pdf does not contain the information which Unicode characters those Canadian glyphs correspond to. In that case text extraction routines can only guess which has a tendency to go wrong.